# How to set up http re-direction in nginx with https

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, nginx, https

Currently running nginx with ssl.

but now, I have to apply http for a particular url case.

I applied the following code but it does not work.

- http url case : https://www.example.com/shop/naverpay/naverpay_item?ITEM_ID=ba00000006

->

http://www.example.com/shop/naverpay/naverpay_item?ITEM_ID=ba00000006

server {

```
listen       80;
server_name  .example.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

}

server {

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name  .example.com;   
root   /home/example.com/www;
client_max_body_size 10M;
keepalive_timeout 70;

#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains preload"; 
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
#add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;

ssl on;
http2_max_requests 4096;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.dhparam;

#OCSP Stapling

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

access_log /home/example.com/log/example.com.access.log;
error_log  /home/example.com/log/example.com.error.log warn;

#rewrite ^/shop/naverpay/(.*).php$  http://www.example.com/shop/naverpay/$1 permanent;

location ~ /shop/naverpay {
    #rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri paramenant;
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}

location / {
    index  index.php index.html;
}

# Block dot file (.htaccess .htpasswd .svn .git .env and so on.)
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
}

# Block .php file inside upload folder. uploads(wp), files(drupal, xe), data(gnuboard).
location ~* /(?:uploads|files|data)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

# Add PHP handler
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/example.com.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
     valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
     if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
    }
}
```

}

result : no-working

my modify position :

```
location ~ /shop/naverpay {
    #rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri paramenant;
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

when all url is redirected to https, I want to know how to make only specific url being http.

Comment: It's impossible, because you use HSTS. That means **all** requests to your server must be via https. No exceptions.

Comment: Anyway, at least you must have an http server block that will process the url.

Comment: really thank you for your reply.
then for solve this issue, Should I make two case of server module for http and https?

If possible, can I get a example source in this case?